# Qt Minimized Taskbar Icon Mouse Event

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, taskbar

I've tried virtually every way possible to hook the activated() signal of a taskbar icon to a corresponding slot. However, I do not understand why Qt(Qt5 Cretor) says I don't have a matching function for the slot.

> **Qt Error:**
>
> C:\Users\potato\Desktop\CCT-master\CCTracker\cctsystemtray.cpp:40:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   'QObject::connect(QSystemTrayIcon*&, const char*, CCTSystemTray*
>   const, const char*)'this,
>   SLOT(systrayActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)))

As far as I can tell, according to [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#activated),

The activated() signal is used to catch mouse events such as clicks and double clicks for the taskbar icon. At first try I thought it's only signals and slots, but then for whatever reason activated() just won't fit. And If I try connecting activated() to a slot from another class, everything fails due to pointer errors.

Here's are the working parts inside **CCTSystemTray.h**:

```
class CCTSystemTray
{
public:
    CCTSystemTray();
    void initSystemTray(QWidget *rootWindow);
private:
    QSystemTrayIcon* systray;

public slots:
    void systrayActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason);
};
```

And **CCTSystemTray.cpp**:

```
// Above are Class declearations, menu items, etc...

QObject::connect(this->systray, SIGNAL(QSystemTrayIcon::activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)),
        this, SLOT(systrayActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
}

void CCTSystemTray::systrayActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)
{
    qDebug() << "Hello";
}
```

The full code sample can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/BRcrgrb4) on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BRcrgrb4).

If someone can help me out from hair-pulling, that'd be great!

Thank you all.

Comment: I think the solution is here http://qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/desktop-systray/. I have tried it once but without luck. I'll try again tomorrow and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your class `CCTSystemTray` has a slot, but it is not a `QObject` (it doesn't derive from QObject or another class derived from QObject) and also you need the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class declaration and then signals and slots will work.

Comment: Aw Thank you. I tried subclassing QObject but that only gave me dreaded qmake and vtable errors. I re-integrated the system tray back with the main window, and it worked. As explained by qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/desktop-systray

Comment: Did you had the Q_OBJECT macro? And also sometimes you might need to manually _run qmake_ (from Build menu in Creator).

Comment: Yeah I did. Implementing the Q_OBJECT macro and along with its constructor, then manually ran qmake, gave me errors I don't quite remember. I did it using Qt's method, which directly implements the systray icon with the main window. It works now.